# Single Sign on with Azure is not working

Tags: single-sign-on, azure

We have done SAML 2.0 Federated SSO settings in salesforce sandbox org. [image: SSO Settings from Salesforce sandbox here]

Azure team refused to import salesforce.com certificate in azure citing security reasons.

I had downloaded metadata and shared metadata file with Azure. But SSO is not working.

Is it required to import SFDC certificate in Azure somewhere?

Another issue is that when I to go my Domain > Authentication Service i don't see my SSO configuration there. Only those configurations which are registered as Auth providers are showing up there.

How can i make my SSO configuration visible under Authentication Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved issue myself by changing SSO settings